# get the hash of an image using react native

Tags: image, hash, react-native

I am trying to get a hash of an image in my react native code.  I already have a function that is successfully getting the hash of a string called calcmd5

I tried getting the hash of my image by using require

```
let hashimage =            calcMD5(require('../assets/fish/biscuitSkate.jpg'))
```

However that is not giving the correct results, does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you need something that gives you the image as a string, (require won't do that, I think it returns an internal asset identifier). What are you comparing the results with?

Comment: There is a server that hosts images and has has the hash of each image, I have to check to see if my hashes match their hashes to work out which ones to download

Comment: do you know if the server md5s the binary or the base64 encoded version of the image?

Comment: You'll probably need a native module for that I'm afraid

Comment: So I will need something separate for android as well as ios?